# How to Publish dotnet webapi application that have mutiple projects to iis

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, publishing

[![this is my webApi project solution structure.this have multiple projects added][1]][1]

how can i publish these kind of projects in visual studio 2019
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z42EP.png

Comment: I would suggest using the Web Deploy tool (https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) if your target IIS is remote. The built-in Visual Studio publishing tool (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-aspnet-web-app?view=vs-2022&tabs=web-server) will automatically build and bundle all of your web project's dependenies into a single deployment package and deploy it to the target IIS if you configure these tools correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming by publish you do not mean you just want the DLL's.

Those are class library projects, they cannot be published by themselves.
If you want to publish a project you need to build either a web api, console application, wpf, web forms, etc. You can then add the class library projects as project references to the project you wish to publish. When you publish one of those projects, the dlls for the class library projects automatically get built along with them.

In the example in the screenshot you provided, you would publish "ThriftPlanningWebApi". That would automatically publish all the dlls for the class libraries along with it.

If you do want the raw DLL's simply build the project in release mode, navigate to the file location of the project. In the bin folder there should be a folder called "release". That folder will contain all your dlls.

Let me know if you need anything else.

Happy coding :)